# SMTP- IIS Email Delivery Issues

Tags: sql, smtp

We have a WEBAPI that uses SQL Database and customers use it to create a report or pull the info from it.

Now the customers want the notifications whenever they have the data available or the reports available. We had set up the IIS/SMTP thinking that it will deliver the emails successfully but the emails are getting delayed or not delivered at all.

We tried checking with the SMTP relay companies but they are also not sure how they can help us other than creating and account etc.

Any possible headsup, what can be checked and what are we missing.

Comment: *"The emails are getting delayed or not delivered at all."* - Please [edit] your question to include the exact details of the behavior you are observing. Relevant email logs would likely be helpful here.

Comment: Why to the question title and the text refer to SQL when this is clearly an email problem? SQL does not, AFAIK, send email. Welcome aboard, but please read [ask]. Good luck :-)